# how to unmarshal with template?

Tags: java, jaxb

i guess error at

```
T bobj = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

it always return null

test with non-template, it work and return a Customer class, only return null when use with template

Original code

```
XMLObj<Customer> XMLtool = new XMLObj<Customer>(Customer.class);
Customer c = XMLtool.ConvertXMLToObject("c:\\file2.xml");

public class XMLObj<T> {
    final Class<T> typeParameterClass;
    public XMLObj(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

public T ConvertXMLToObject(String path)
    {
        //Convert XML to Object
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            if(file.exists())
            {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext;
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                T bobj = (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                System.out.println(bobj);
                return bobj;
            }
            else
                Logger.getInstance().process_message("File not exist in ConvertObjectToXML");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Logger.getInstance().process_message(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass.getClass());
```

To this:

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass);
```

`typeParameterClass.getClass()` returns a type of class of `java.lang.Class`, whereas `typeParameterClass` itself has type of class of `Customer` which is the class you want to unmarshal.